# Z-Index: Divs still overlap in the wrong order (browserwide)

Tags: css, z-index

I can't select one of those dropdrown-links, although the #header div has a higher z-index than the rest. All relevant divs are in the same level but do not align properly:

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/4245/zindex.png

```
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navigation">
            </div>
  </div>  
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content">
                           ...
  </div>


#header {
 width: 915px;
 height: 76px;
 z-index: 5;
}
#content {
 width: 677px;
 height: 412px;
 margin-left: 202px;
 z-index:1;
}

#sidebar { 
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 448px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation {
    height: 28px;
    width: 915px;
    float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add position relative to the elements that need to obey z-index. From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

> z-index only works on positioned
>   elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Although, from  your image I do not see a reason to be using z-index other than maybe the drop down navigation.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only applies to positioned (i.e. `position: /* not static */`) elements.

Change the positioning property valud.